# Trouble Creating Android ClientID to use with AppAuth Library for Android

Tags: android, appauth

I want to use [AppAuth-Android](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/) for openID sign in within my app.

My problem is that no matter how I create a Client ID for Android I continue to receive redirect_uri 400 errors.  Adding a Client ID for Android doesnt clearly show what redirect_uri is or needs to be and when I just use the package name of my app I end up with a redirect_uri_mismatch.

[image: Adding Client ID for Android doesnt clearly show what redirect_uri is or needs to be]

I have gone through the [codelabs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appauth-android-codelab) created by google and everything seemed straightforward.

However, now that I am trying to get everything setup in my app, there is not enough detail around exactly what steps need to be taken to create a client_id and a redirect_uri that will work for the custom scheme in my app.

Here's a picture of the slide where it assumes I'll be able to correctly create a client_id:
[image: A depiction of exactly the step that I need more detail on]

I have found plenty of documentation from google with advice on what to do but none of it has included enough details to get me around this issue which I have spent way too many hours on.  The most useful page that I found here was the section on [OAuth2 for Mobile & Desktop](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#libraries)

Can anyone provide the exact steps to take within [Google's API Credential manager](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials) to create a client_id for my existing android app that will be able to work in the exact same manner as the codelabs tutorial referenced above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with copy/pasting the client_id and I was too focused on the error message related to the redirect_uri to figure it out without taking a long break away.

Here are some items I can clarify in case someone else ends up banging their head over the same issue.

To resolve the redirect_uri problem I had, I went back through and made sure that:

1. The Client ID matched the one in the google api console and that the google api console had the correct package name for my app.

   > "com.examplepackagename"
2. The custom scheme declared in my manifest matched the app's package name directly.

> ```
>     <activity
>         android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
>         tools:node="replace">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
>             <data android:scheme="com.examplepackagename"/>
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> ```

3. The redirect uri passed by the app followed the example of the code lab and was formatted like

> "com.examplepackagename:/oauth2callback"